# javascript function doesn't responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Simple thing!!..In asp.net- MVC project. i have a button . and i have a external javascript file `mydata.js`. in that file contains a function `checkJS()`.

```
function checkJs()
{
   debugger;
   alert("your output!!!");
}
```

My code:

```
<div id="mydivid" style="background-color:lightblue;">
   STAGE
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnid" value="Load Data" />
```

When i click a button , Its just call the jQuery click function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnid").click(function (event) {
      debugger;
      $.getScript('mydata.js', function() {
         // debugger;
          checkJs();
      });

   });
});
```

I used initialy 1.12.4.js library file in the head tag
and i added my external js file in head tag.

what is the problem in my code. why the button click did not reached the external method.

Comment: Does the `debugger` get hit?

Comment: @haim770 debugger of external js file doesn't hitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Make sure that jQuery library added before your external java-script file.

When you ensure the first point do like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnid").click(function (event) {
       checkJs();
    });
});
```

2.If you want to use `$.getScript()` then do like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnid").click(function (event) {
      $.getScript('mydata.js').done(function(data, textStatus) { // check the file path of mydata.js is correct or not?
         checkJs();
      });
    });
});
```

The above code will work only when you have jQuery library added before this code and you remove the external JavaScript file path from your head.

***Note:-***

***data***:- returned data from external script

***textStatus***:- status of the call to external script (plain-text like "Success")

For more knowledge check this link:- [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: Hey your code are nice and simple. i know its work.. But my thing this ` $.getScript('mydata.js', function() {
         //      debugger;
               checkJs();
            });` need to call like this. is that any wrong in my code

Comment: can u please tell me that the use of   `(script, textstatus)`

Comment: @User6667769  glad to help you :):):)

Answer (score 2):

You can directly call your function without `getScript` if you have already included the `mydata.js` in head.

If not, and want to do it with `getScript` then make sure you are giving correct path, load js in done callback and if still not then check if calls goes to `fail` callback.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnid").click(function (event) {
      debugger;

       $.getScript('mydata.js').done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
          checkJs();
       }).fail(function(){
           if(arguments[0].readyState==0){
           //script failed to load
           }else{
             //script loaded but failed to parse
             alert(arguments[2].toString());
           }
       })
    });
});
```

Done callback has 3 parameters with has following values in it.

1. data: has the returned data(script)
2. textStatus: it returns the status in plain text, e.g. "Success"
3. jqxhr : its jqXHR object, which is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object and has the "status" property which returns status code.

Comment: hey Instead of putting `$.getScript('/Scripts/jsondata.js', function(script, textStatus) {
         //      debugger;
               checkJs();  
          });`    i simply did like this `$.getScript('/Scripts/jsondata.js', function(jd) {
         //      debugger;
               checkJs();  
          });` i mean i added some parameter for the method...can u please tell me that the use of   `(script, textstatus)`

Comment: Actually your code work for me. i mean the original code. before your edited

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply buddy!!.

Comment: Welcome. I have updated the answer with param description.